# java scanner not working in terminal

Tags: java, linux, ant, terminal, java.util.scanner

I have tried this on a Mac terminal and a Linux Mint terminal as well as Windows via a cmd terminal (on two different machines). I am running the test through a build.xml file and I am using ant 1.8.2 and Java 1.6. It just hangs after I type in the input. The exact same code works from within eclipse or by compiling and running manually (i.e. javac.. and then java...). Any help would be appreciated..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        System.err.println("Enter Something...");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.next();

        System.err.println("Entered: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: See here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#background

Answer (score 0):

Try running your project with an older version of ant. There seems to be a bug(50960) already filed for a similar problem. This is fixed in 1.8.3. 
Check the following links:

http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/bug-in-ant-1-8-2-read-on-System-in-hangs-for-forked-java-task-td4258253.html

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50960